# Dagger 2 Injector and Binds IntoMap with IntKey

Tags: android, dagger-2, androidinjector

I'm using `Dagger 2` Android injector to inject my `Activities` and `Fragments`.

I have a generic `RecyclerView` Adapter and keeping `ViewHolderFactories` and `Binders` in a `Map`.

Here's my adapter:

```
@Module
class CorePresentationModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideDisplayItemComperator(): DisplayItemComperator = DefaultDisplayItemComperator()

    @Module
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @Provides
        fun provideRecyclerAdapter(
            itemComparator: DisplayItemComperator,
            factoryMap: Map<Int, @JvmSuppressWildcards ViewHolderFactory>,
            binderMap: Map<Int, @JvmSuppressWildcards ViewHolderBinder>,
            androidPreconditions: AndroidPreconditions
        ): RecyclerViewAdapter {
            return RecyclerViewAdapter(
                itemComperator = itemComparator,
                viewHolderFactoryMap = factoryMap,
                viewBinderFactoryMap = binderMap,
                androidPreconditions = androidPreconditions
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I crate a presentation module for my Fragment like the following:

```
@Module
abstract class MessagesPresentationModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @IntKey(MESSAGE)
    internal abstract fun provideMessagesViewModelFactory(factory: MessagesViewHolder.MessageViewHolderFactory): ViewHolderFactory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @IntKey(MESSAGE)
    internal abstract fun provideMessagesViewHolderBinder(binder: MessagesViewHolder.MessagesViewHolderBinder): ViewHolderBinder

}
```

In another fragment i inject my adapter again and create another module for my screen:

```
@Module
abstract class LinksPresentationModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @IntKey(LINK)
    internal abstract fun provideLinksViewModelFactory(factory: LinksViewHolder.LinksViewHolderFactory): ViewHolderFactory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @IntKey(LINK)
    internal abstract fun provideLinksViewHolderBinder(binder: LinksViewHolder.LinksViewHolderBinder): ViewHolderBinder

}
```

When `MESSAGE` and `LINK` is 0 i get a compile error

> The same map key is bound more than once for `ViewHolderFactory`

What's is the best solution to get avoid this execpt putting all `IntKeys` in a constants class with ordered and incremented?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After long research in my code, I found the missing point. I provide my `presentation modules` in `Application component` so it generates only one Map for each type and gets this duplicate `MapKey` error.

> The same map key is bound more than once for ViewHolderFactory

I found [this](https://proandroiddev.com/dagger-2-annotations-binds-contributesandroidinjector-a09e6a57758f) useful article in Medium. I realised that created my modules for `Application Scope`. So `SubComponents` for my presentation modules does not get generated and `Dagger` creates only one Map for factory classes. I redesigned my `Dagger` implementation for my presentation modules to keep them `FragmentScoped` as it should be like the following code.

```
@Module
abstract class MessagesFragmentModule {
    @FragmentScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MessagesPresentationModule::class]
    abstract fun contributeMessagesFragment(): MessagesFragment
}

@Module
abstract class LinksFragmentModule {
    @FragmentScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [LinksPresentationModule::class]
    abstract fun provideLinksFragment(): LinksFragment
}
```

And here's `ActivityModule`

```
@Module
internal abstract class ActivityModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(
        modules = [MessagesFragmentModule::class,
            LinksFragmentModule::class]
    )
    @ActivityScope
    abstract fun provideMainActivityContributor(): MainActivity
}
```